# Do I need ValidateAntiForgeryToken on a Login action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

It makes only some sense that this filter is, by default (i.e. by scaffolding) applied to the a `Login` action, as far as I know, this token works best when already associated with a login id. With it applied to `Login`, I have a problem if the user tries to log in twice, with an error such as

> The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "", but the current
>   user is "[theLoggedInUser]".

Now a user logging in twice wouldn't normally be a problem, but for this, so the added effort of preventing this makes less sense, subject to answers to this question, than simply removing the validation from the login action.

Comment: This happened on my apps when user double clicks on the Login button. What I did was I disable the button on the first click... Problem vanish!

Comment: We had the same error on our login form, primarily when the user logged in, clicked the back button, then tried to login again. Our solution was to not allow the login page to be cached by adding the attribute [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)] to the login action method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should use it. Using a cookie and the hidden form value it inserts, it helps prevent nefarious users from impersonating your site and maliciously POSTing requests.

<strike>This of course, would be where ypu verify your users account details.  Without it, someone could write a script to brute force attack the server, in an attempt to guess a user's login and password combo. By using the validate antiforgery feature, each request is guarenteed to fail even if the script would generate the right password.</strike>

This is just one tool out of many to make sure that people can access your site's functuons in the way you desire.

EDIT: Updated based on comment, but point still stands. Use it ;)

Comment: Actually, if the attacker can just guess the user's credentials through brute-force methods (or any other method), the attacker already has the keys to the kingdom without performing a CSRF attack.  So, anti-forgery tokens will not prevent that kind of attack.  However, there are still good reasons to use anti-forgery tokens on login forms, as explained here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/when-the-use-of-a-antiforgerytoken-is-not-required-needed

Comment: Are you sure?  I edited my answer to be on the safe side, but if a hacker (a very bad one) kept spamming the LOGIN action of the server with malicious requests - from let's say - the command line, they should all fail because of the lack of anti-forgery token.  Now, if this hacker was to write a script that would hit up a fresh login page via a browser window with each try, that would be different (and substantially more difficult to do).

Comment: Actually, the anti-forgery token is easy to get...it's given to you every time you request a login page (or other page protected with the token).  If I want to script a brute-force login attack that runs from my own computer, all I have to do is write a program to request the login page, parse the token from the HTML, and then send my login request with the token.  However, JavaScript CANNOT download pages from other websites, so it can't access the token.  Therefore, the the token protects against a cross-site attacks, but not against direct brute force attacks, or any other direct attack.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a reason to use the anti forgery token on forms that do not require authentication to use. The reason is, the AFT is meant to prevent cross site request forgeries, where some malicious code uses your already logged-in user to do unauthorized requests to some site on your behalf. Thus, posting as "your" anonymous user could be done even without hi-jacking your request. I can see some pretty far fetched scenario where a black hat wants to use someone else's IP address to do the posting, but that doesn't seem too realistic.

If I am wrong about this, please enlighten me, so I too can learn something new and better my ways.

Comment: I thought the same.  But, then I read this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/when-the-use-of-a-antiforgerytoken-is-not-required-needed

Answer (score 0):

I think you know *why to use anti-forgery*, So I place some tips and solutions here.

The error is happening in some cases *because the anti-forgery token embeds the username of the user as part of the encrypted token for better validation*.

*There are lots of people who double click on everything - this is not good!*
You can removed the validation attribute, while your site be *SSL enabled*. Any way, Solutions to solve could be:

1. Disabling the submit button (with js) after click
2. Create a partial view with just `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` and after
   logging in, do another AJAX request update the anti-forgery token
   with the response of the request
3. Disable the identity check for anti-forgery by Adding
   `AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks = true` to your
   *Application_Start* method

Answer (score 0):

You can use but, if you're checking for operations have been made twice or more, you change your perspective from anti-forgery to spam. The twice or more actions can be categorized as spam events. If you want to prevent to this situations, you should write some code like;

```
public class PreventSpamAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    //This stores the time between Requests (in seconds)
    public int DelayRequest = 10;
    //The Error Message that will be displayed in case of excessive Requests
    public string ErrorMessage = "Excessive Request Attempts Detected.";
    public string ErrorResouceKey = string.Empty;
    //This will store the URL to Redirect errors to
    public string RedirectUrl;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //Store our HttpContext (for easier reference and code brevity)
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        //Store our HttpContext.Cache (for easier reference and code brevity)
        var cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Cache;

        //Grab the IP Address from the originating Request (very simple implementation for example purposes)
        var originationInfo = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ?? request.UserHostAddress;

        //Append the User Agent
        originationInfo += request.UserAgent;

        //Now we just need the target URL Information
        var targetInfo = request.RawUrl + request.QueryString;

        //Generate a hash for your strings (this appends each of the bytes of the value into a single hashed string
        var hashValue = string.Join("", MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(originationInfo + targetInfo)).Select(s => s.ToString("x2")));

        //Checks if the hashed value is contained in the Cache (indicating a repeat request)
        if (cache[hashValue] != null)
        {
            //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ATTENTION !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            //Adds the Error Message to the Model and Redirect

            //or

            //Force the action to do anythning!!!!!

            // My business Solution : 
            //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorResouceKey)) //if error will getting from resouce
            //{
            //    throw new BusinessException(ResourceHelper.Current.GetKeyValue(ErrorResouceKey));
            //}

            //throw new BusinessException(ErrorMessage);
        }
        //Adds an empty object to the cache using the hashValue to a key (This sets the expiration that will determine
        //if the Request is valid or not
        //cache.Add(hashValue, null, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(DelayRequest), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Default, null);

        cache.Add(hashValue, 1, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(DelayRequest), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

While Using (you can change the error handling strategy);

```
   [PreventSpam(DelayRequest = 5, ErrorMessage = "Please try again in 5 seconds.")]
   public virtual JsonResult Login()
   {
   }
```